# Changing the title of a dynamically generated dialog

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm using tinymce with my own File Browser:

```
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) 
{ 
   tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
   title: 'My Title',
   url : 'file_browser.html',
}
```

I wish to dynamically change the title, "My Title" of the dialog using javascript from within the file_browser.html iframe.

The html generated by tinymce looks something like this:

```
<div id="mceu_76-head" class="mce-window-head"><div id="mceu_76-title" class="mce-title">My title</div></div>

<div id="mceu_76-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout"><iframe src="file_browser.html" tabindex="-1">
```

Obviously I can't use `getElementById("mceu_76-head")` since this is dynamically generated and there are other dialogs whose Title I don't wish to change. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windowManager.open returns window settings which contains the id.

```
var win = tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
   title: 'My Title',
   url : 'file_browser.html',
   ...
});

document.getElementById(win._id + '-title').innerHTML = 'New Title';
```

It works but I'm not sure it is right way.

Comment: According to the documentation open() returns void: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.WindowManager.open

Comment: Though the documentation said that, it actually returns window settings object in v4. You can find the related code in WindowManager.js in 4.x dev package.